# How can I remove an ArrayList from an ArrayList of ArrayLists?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> b = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
```

I have an ArrayList like the one above with a bunch of ArrayLists as elements, is there a way to remove one of them by index?

I created a `for` loop to remove one of the ArrayLists and got an error message that says there are
incompatible types.

```
for(int f = 0; f < longDistanceInput.size(); f++){
     ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> newLongDisinput = longDistanceInput.remove(f);
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [`b.remove(index)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove-int-)

Comment: you can remove anything from an `ArrayList` of any object type – it's irrelevant what the `ArrayList` contains

Comment: Just a hint: You usually use the interface (List) as type, not the implementation (ArrayList).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I tried to do something like this and got an error message says
>   incompatible types
>
> ```
> for(int f = 0; f<longDistanceInput.size(); f ++){
>    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> newLongDisinput = longDistanceInput.remove(f);}
> ```

That's because `longDistanceInput.remove(f)` returns a `ArrayList<String>`, not a `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>`.

Try:

```
ArrayList<String> newLongDisinput = longDistanceInput.remove(f);
```

However: be careful removing things while iterating forwards: you will end up removing only half the items in the list, because you skip over the one immediately after the one you remove.

Either iterate in reverse; or just use `longDistanceInput.remove(0)` instead of `remove(f)`. But note that removing from anything but the large-index end of an `ArrayList` is rather inefficient: if possible, just don't remove things from the list until after the loop.